# How Crashlytics Mac app works?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, crashlytics

Crashlytics somehow talks to XCode:

- It detects project opened in XCode.
- It detects list of recent projects.
- It detects builds.
- Uploads symbolication automatically.
- Knows when you've added Crashlytics framework into your XCode project and built it.
- etc.

Is it all about watching for changes in all `DerivedData/...` folders (opened projects, resent projects, builds) and then running something like `nm BINARY | grep Crashlytics` (static library linking detection) or there are better tools available?

Answer (score 0):

For detecting projects opened in Xcode, I'd say it watches folders or even hooks onto opened applications.

For projects on disk I assume it scans for `.xcworkspace` and `.xcodeproj` directories.

For detecting builds, it adds a Run phase script to your target. This is how detects builds, knows when it is added to the project and uploads symbolication files to Crashlytics server.